# Where does docker volume map . on the host?

Tags: docker

I'm on a windows 10 machine, in powershell, trying to mount a folder. I thought using "." in the path, it would be mapped to the current directory, but obviously not

```
cd c:/
docker run -it -v ./uniquename:/var/uniquename alpine sh
/ # touch /var/uniquename/test
/ # ls /var/uniquename
test
/ # exit
cd c:/tmp
docker run -it -v ./uniquename:/var/uniquename alpine sh
/ # ls /var/uniquename
test
/ # exit
```

Now, my question is not how to map a volume relative to the current directory - that would be $(pwd) or "use absolute paths" or whatever. My question is:

Where on my host is the mapped folder and newly created file located?

Comment: I would have thought it was powershell's fault, but I see the same behavior in cmd.exe

Comment: May you try to use "docker inspect <containerid>" to view the mounted folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out docker strips out the ./ resulting in the -v flag grabbing the "uniquename" as the name of a `docker volume`.

```
> docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               uniquename
```

Mystery solved. Figuring out where docker stores volumes is left as an excersize to the reader.